# Trying to convert plural words into singular but it deletes any 's'

Tags: java, regex

Trying to convert plural words into singular in Java for example `foxes` into `fox` but something is wrong that it deletes any `'s'`

File Reader function as follows:

```
public static String readFileAsString(String fileName) throws Exception {
    String data = "";
    data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    return data;
}
```

Singularity converter function as follows;

```
public static String singular(String data) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("");
    if (Pattern.matches("(/ss)$", data)) {
        data = data.replaceAll("(s|es)", (" "));
    } else {
        data = data.replaceAll("(s|es)", (" "));
    }

    return data;
}
```

Actually I'm aware that i shouldn't be using `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("");`
But I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: What should `Andreas` be converted to?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to go through a sex change and become a woman. Nothing wrong with women named Andrea, but that's not me.

Comment: You are using ``replaceAll("(s|es)", " ")``. This finds all instances of s or es, and replaces them with a space. You need to look at just those s's that end a word.

Comment: @korhan-aladag what about the `horses` ?

Comment: I want to change horses into horse but i don't really know how to apply that distinction @Hülya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want a simple solution that looks for `s` or `es` at the end of a *word*, and removes them.

To do that, you need to ensure that the found `s` or `es` is at the end of a word, i.e. at least one letter before, and no letters after. For that, use the `\b` word boundary and `\B` non-word boundary patterns.

Instead of `(s|es)` you should use optional `e` followed by `s`, i.e. `e?s`

```java
data = data.replaceAll("\\Be?s\\b", "");
```

*Example*

```java
String data = "The quick brown foxes jumps over the lazy dogs";
data = data.replaceAll("\\Be?s\\b", "");
System.out.println(data);
```

*Output*

```
The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog
```

Notice how the flawed premise of the code (that all words ending with `s` are plural words) also changes `jumps` to `jump`.

Comment: what about the `horses` ?

Comment: @Hülya They become hors d'oeuvre.